# How to slide in UIView from bottom in Landscape Mode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, animation, uiview

I have added a UIView to another 'main' view on IB. My application is in landscape mode only. I want to make it so that by pressing a button, this other UIView slides in from the bottom. So, currently it's not in the picture at all, but when the button is pressed, then the view appears from the bottom and slides into place. Later I will have the same button work as a toggle to then slide the UIVIew back out. The UIView is not the size of the screen, otherwise I would have presented it modally.

This is the code I've tried:

.m

```
-(IBAction)onGearBag:(UIButton *)sender
{

    [sender setEnabled:NO];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
        if (gearBag.transform.ty == 0) {
            [gearBag setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -400)];
        }else{
            [gearBag setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -200)];
        }
    }completion:^(BOOL done){
        //some completion handler
        [sender setEnabled:YES];
    }];
}
```

.h

```
@interface MyEquipmentViewController : PFViewController
{
    IBOutlet UIView *gearBag;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) TabsTopBar *topbar;
- (IBAction)onPopoverButton:(UIButton *)sender;
- (IBAction)actionHelp:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)onGearBag:(id)sender;
@end
```

.h

```
@interface MyEquipmentViewController : PFViewController
{
    IBOutlet UIView *popoverInitAlert;
    __unsafe_unretained IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
    IBOutlet UIView *gearBag;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) TabsTopBar *topbar;
- (IBAction)onPopoverButton:(UIButton *)sender;
- (IBAction)actionHelp:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)onGearBag:(id)sender;
@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple view animation:

```
- (IBAction)myIBAction:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [sender setEnabled:NO];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
        if (mySecondView.transform.ty == 0) {
            [mySecondView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -400)];
        }else{
            [mySecondView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0)];
        }
    }completion:^(BOOL done){
        //some completion handler
        [sender setEnabled:YES];
    }];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've tried that, but when I press my Button, nothing is happening.

Comment: @GinoF Have you properly linked an IBOutlet to your UIView in interface builder?

Comment: @GinoF It looks like you declared `- (IBAction)onGearBag:(id)sender;` in your .h, but used `- (IBAction)onGearBag:(UIButton *)sender;` in your .m replace `id` with `UIButton *` in your .h then relink the outlet in interface builder.

Comment: I did this...but still not working. Sorry about this. Any ideas why it's not working? I relinked the button as you said and made sure that a IBOutlet is linked to my UIView.

Comment: @GinoF Just a thought, does the new view have anything in it to indicate to you that it is moving, a plain empty view may be moving but you just can't see it. Either way the problem is somewhere else, I just wrote and tested this code for you and it works.

Comment: Yea I checked and the UIView has a white background. So I at least should be seeing that. Thanks for testing it though. I'll keep tinkering with it until it works. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @GinoF Glad to help! If my answer ends up solving your original problem then be sure to mark it as correct by clicking the "check mark" next to my post! :)

Comment: Thank you so much! Finally got it to work. It was my mistake all along (obviously). Had the sub-view outside of the main view.