# Slide in UIView

Tags: objective-c, swift, uiview

What is the most elegant/ cleanest way to add a custom UIView sliding from the bottom of the screen?

Should I create custom UIView in its own xib and then add it below the view and animate it or is there a better way?

Comment: You can add sliding view by container.

Comment: You create a custom popup view and animate it from bottom. That is best way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to slide in UIView from bottom in Landscape Mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12545048/how-to-slide-in-uiview-from-bottom-in-landscape-mode)

Comment: @fishinear I would not agree. I am just simply asking about overall steps that other, more experienced developers do while creating a slide in custom UIView.

Comment: @Ancinek if you are only asking for overall steps, then I would close the question because it is too broad/opinion based. On SO, you need to show what you have researched and tried and what is not working.